# Post HTML <form> on load

Tags: html, forms, post, onload

What is the best way to post a HTML Form on load? This is what I'm currently trying:

```
<?php  
 if ($Autopost == "1");
 {
   <body onLoad="mail.submit()">
   <form method="POST" name="mail" class="adjacent" action="./Script/addmaillist.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="genre" value="<?php echo $genre; ?>">
   </form>
 }
?>
```

I would just like to know if this is a good way, and if there is a better way?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why? You appear to already have server-side code, you can just run the relevant code as if the form had been submitted, can't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Kolink that it seems unnecessary to send information to the client and then back to the server, but assuming you need to do that for some reason, you could use Javascript and jQuery to post a form through the `$(document).ready()` event, which triggers and runs its contents upon page load. So you would have your form with id="mail" and in your script you could have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mail").submit();
}
```

Comment: Im trying to do it in HTML, cause I dont want to change the ./Script/addmaillist.php, To prevent any troubles with other addons.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any server-side code to submit on-load. also, your code doesn't look quiet right. is that in php?

Answer (score 0):

There are some small syntax errors in your code:

```
<?php  
if ($Autopost == "1")
{ ?>
   <body onLoad="mail.submit()">
   <form method="POST" name="mail" class="adjacent" action="./Script/addmaillist.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="genre" value="<?php echo $genre; ?>" />
   </form>
<?php
}
?>
```